# Determine the values of x and y but they have infinitely many solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is a question from this year's South African Matric Final exam

---

*Determine the values of x and y if:
$$\frac{3^{y+1}}{32} = \sqrt{96^x}$$*
The solution, according to my teacher, is as followed:
$$\frac{3^{y+1}}{2^5} = \sqrt{2^{5x} \times 3^x }\\
\frac{3^{2y+2}}{2^{10}} = 2^{5x} \times 3^x \\
\frac{3^{2y+2}}{2^{10}} = \frac{3^x}{2^{-5x}} \\$$
Hence:
$$2y + 2 = x\\
10=-5x\\
x = -2 \\y = -2$$
However, I tried to write everything in terms of y and got this:
$$ y =  \log_3\left({\frac{2^{\frac{5}{2}x}\times 3^{\frac{1}{2}x} \times 2^5}{3}}\right)$$
Doesn't this mean there are technically infinitely many solutions? or am I simply just wrong.
(I've  tested this equation and it does hold for $x = -2$)

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$ ? Integers ?

Comment: No, I've quoted the question word by word. It doesn't specify the type of number

Comment: Take $\log$ of both sides, it is a line. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3%5E%28y%2B1%29%2F32%3D96%5E%28x%2F2%29

Comment: If $x,y$ are integers the unique solution is the one established by your teacher. If they are real numbers, there is an infinity of solutions obtained by taking the logarithm of both sides $(y+1) \ln 3 - \ln 32 = x \frac12 \ln 96$ which is the equation of a straight line.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! But how do you confirm that doing that would give you all the integer solutions?

Comment: @Goamhobala Then, the exercise is , as pointed out , ill-posed since whether $x,y$ can be arbitary reals or have to be integers is crucial for the answer.